# How to delete specific prefix from directory name by shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I created several directly like following

```
admin_users/
admin_cars/
admin_roles/
admin_.../
... other 8 directories.
```

Now, I want to **move** these files to admin directory, and delete suffix.

```
users
cars
roles
... other 8 directories.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to copy, or move?

Comment: I want to move.
@oguzismail

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you. 
I try to improve my question.

@jww

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`[p]rename`](https://metacpan.org/pod/rename) (which is available on most systems):

```
rename 's/_/\//' admin_*/
```

`admin_*/` expands to directories whose name starts with `admin_`, and `s/_/\//` replaces the first underscore with a slash.

Comment: this doesn't do copy, instead, it changes the original directory.

Comment: @Kent See [OP's comment](//stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/104159382)

Comment: ok, then it is the problem of the question...  but your command doesn't do `mv` either.

Comment: Sorry, My Question was wrong.
This perfectly works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So, I take that you want to delete the prefix 'admin'?
If you are sure that that's going to be the name of your directory, you can manually create the directory admin.

After that,

> - you can loop through the current directory (provided you run the script from the concerned directory)
> - find all the directories
> - extract the part after the underscore
> - use it to rename and move in the admin directory.

Something along the lines of this --

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in `ls -l | grep "^d" | awk '{print $9}'`; do
    suff=`echo $file | cut -d '_' -f 2`
    echo $suff
    mv $file admin/$suff
done
```

Comment: As You can say, I want to delete prefix admin.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: and `grep|awk` is not that wise

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I want to **copy** these files to admin directory, and delete suffix.

You said you want to **Copy** those directories to another parent dir. `cp` command supports defining the target file name:

```
cp -r admin_users /path/to/admin/users
```

You can just write a loop for that. For the "removing prefix" part, say `f` is the variable in your loop:

```
kent$  echo $f
admin_users
kent$  echo "/path/to/admin/${f##admin_}"
/path/to/admin/users
```